# Missing PhotonNetwork.autoCleanUpPlayerObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am currently using PUN 2.20.1. I'm trying to instantiate an object in the room and facing two issues.

1. PhotonNetwork.InstantiateRoomObject works only for the master. When called on the client-side (non-master) it returns null.

2.There is no autocleanupPlayerObjects property available.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeybD.png)
I looked into the documentation but didn't find any answers. Any help is deeply appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

1. That's by design: only master client can instantiate room objects. You can read more about this [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation#lifetime_of_networked_objects) or [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/ownershipandcontrol#room_object).
2. You can find the answer here in [PUN Classic to PUN 2 Migration Notes](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/migration-notes#api_changes). You can use `PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.AutoCleanUp` instead.

> PhotonNetwork.autoCleanUpPlayerObjects is gone. The setting is per room, so it's now in the RoomOptions. Example: PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null, new RoomOptions() { CleanupCacheOnLeave = true });

In both cases we can improve the documentation but you could also make use of the doc search (examples: [1](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/search?p=pun&v=v2&addsearch=InstantiateRoomObject) and [2](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/search?p=pun&v=v2&addsearch=autoCleanUpPlayerObjects)).